# Exclude some documents, wrong query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using this query to get some documents:

```
    $rawQuery = array(
        'query' => array(
            'custom_score' => array(
                'query'  => array(
                    'bool' => array(
                        'must'     => array(
                            "terms"=> ...
                        )                       
                    ),
                ),
                'script' => "_score * ...."
            )
        ),
        'from'  => $from,
        'size'  => $size,
    );
```

What I'd like is including something like this:

```
'must_not' => array('terms' => array('is_something' => 'no')),
```

but I don't figure out where I should put this, I tried in the same level of "must", but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In the must_not I changed the "terms" for "term" and worked.